How to format Power Automate email SharePoint links to look like manually pasted SharePoint links do
How do I get the SharePoint file & folder links in Power Automate generated emails to look like SharePoint links you paste in manually and not like standard HTML links?
Standard HTML Link formatting: 
Desired SharePoint link formatting: 

Are you just asking about the folder icon? The links look identical otherwise. The background color (and the image, too) might depend on the e-mail client used. Note that if users have HTML formatting turned off for incoming e-mails, they will not see either of these looks in their e-mail, for example.

@TylerH basically I'm looking for a way of getting it auto formatted as it does when you paste URL into the body of the message manually, so folder icons for folders, app icons for docs etc.
